# Add css to flash tags trough javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Joomla with "ZT Cu3er 3D Slideshow" I am trying crack this nut i need to add transparency to both objects

```
style="opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"
```

someone who knows javascript help.
it pulls with code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        flashvars.xml = "http://cre8tivesyndicateworldwide.com/modules/mod_zt_cu3er/assets/config/config_26.xml";       
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.wmode = "transparent";
        attributes.id = "slider26";
        swfobject.embedSWF("http://cre8tivesyndicateworldwide.com/modules/mod_zt_cu3er/assets/cu3er.swf", "jv_cu3er26", "940", "400", "9", "http://cre8tivesyndicateworldwide.com/modules/mod_zt_cu3er/assets/js/swfobject/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
</script>
/* Cross-browser dynamic SWF creation
*/
function createSWF(attObj, parObj, id) {
    var r, el = getElementById(id);
    if (ua.wk && ua.wk < 312) { return r; }
    if (el) {
        if (typeof attObj.id == UNDEF) { // if no 'id' is defined for the object element, it will inherit the 'id' from the alternative content
            attObj.id = id;
        }
        if (ua.ie && ua.win) { // Internet Explorer + the HTML object element + W3C DOM methods do not combine: fall back to outerHTML
            var att = "";
            for (var i in attObj) {
                if (attObj[i] != Object.prototype[i]) { // filter out prototype additions from other potential libraries
                    if (i.toLowerCase() == "data") {
                        parObj.movie = attObj[i];
                    }
                    else if (i.toLowerCase() == "styleclass") { // 'class' is an ECMA4 reserved keyword
                        att += ' class="' + attObj[i] + '"';
                    }
                    else if (i.toLowerCase() != "classid") {
                        att += ' ' + i + '="' + attObj[i] + '"';
                    }
                }
            }
            var par = "";
            for (var j in parObj) {
                if (parObj[j] != Object.prototype[j]) { // filter out prototype additions from other potential libraries
                    par += '<param name="' + j + '" value="' + parObj[j] + '" />';
                }
            }
            el.outerHTML = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"' + att + '>' + par + '</object>';
            objIdArr[objIdArr.length] = attObj.id; // stored to fix object 'leaks' on unload (dynamic publishing only)
            r = getElementById(attObj.id);  
        }
        else { // well-behaving browsers
            var o = createElement(OBJECT);
            o.setAttribute("type", FLASH_MIME_TYPE);
            for (var m in attObj) {
                if (attObj[m] != Object.prototype[m]) { // filter out prototype additions from other potential libraries
                    if (m.toLowerCase() == "styleclass") { // 'class' is an ECMA4 reserved keyword
                        o.setAttribute("class", attObj[m]);
                    }
                    else if (m.toLowerCase() != "classid") { // filter out IE specific attribute
                        o.setAttribute(m, attObj[m]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (var n in parObj) {
                if (parObj[n] != Object.prototype[n] && n.toLowerCase() != "movie") { // filter out prototype additions from other potential libraries and IE specific param element
                    createObjParam(o, n, parObj[n]);
                }
            }
            el.parentNode.replaceChild(o, el);
            r = o;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

function createObjParam(el, pName, pValue) {
    var p = createElement("param");
    p.setAttribute("name", pName);  
    p.setAttribute("value", pValue);
    el.appendChild(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define the `style` for the swf `object`, if you use swfobject to embed, it can be referenced with the same ID as you use for initializing the flash:

```
document.getElementById("jv_cu3er26").style.opacity = "0.4";
document.getElementById("jv_cu3er26").style.filter = "alpha(opacity=40)";
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Ruh5s/